# How to use another external xml view android?

Tags: android, xml

I have a view xml file `abc.xml`, which is a `Linearlayout`.

I also have another xml file `def.xml`, in which i want to use `abc.xml`. I am wondering how I can write this within my `def.xml` file?

My `def.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts

Answer (score 0):

That is how :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/abc"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```